# Override CSS for only login page via local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, css

How can I override a `CSS` class selector only my footer on the login page?

login page is the default login page which is copied and loaded from

> `/theme/package/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`

The page identifier seems to be:

> `customer-account-login`

But my `CSS` has no effect. How can I do this?

**'local.xml' contains this code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <layout version="0.1.0">
     <!-- Login Page -->
     <customer-account-login>
        <reference name="head">
          <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <file>css/login.css</file>
          </action>
        </reference>
     </customer-account-login>
  </layout>
```

'login.css' file is this (which what I want to apply to the footer container):

```
.footer-container { height:185px; padding:0px 0px 10px 0px; position:absolute; bottom:0; width:98%; }
```

Comment: Do you want to change footer style only for login page??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `local.xml` layout handle to `customer_account_login`, It should be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <layout version="0.1.0">
     <!-- Login Page -->
     <customer_account_login>
        <reference name="head">
          <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <file>css/login.css</file>
          </action>
        </reference>
     </customer_account_login>
  </layout>
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked, thanks!
Not sure who was quicker with the answer :)

Comment: @Dan No worries its just a few second difference

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong handler

instead

```
<customer-account-login>
```

Use

```
<customer_account_login>
```

it should be `_` not `-`

Comment: Ahhh, few seconds faster :)

Comment: @KeyurShah Yes, Just a few seconds difference

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala: bro how are you

Comment: @RameshS sorry for late reply , I am good how are you ?

Comment: Answer from Keyur showed on top so assumed it was first. Happy to change?

Comment: @Dan no need to do that it's okay